# Why isn't Java's TimSort implementation concurrent?

Tags: java, sorting, concurrency, sequential, timsort

Why is Java's [Tim Sort implementation](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~martin/webrevs/openjdk7/timsort/raw_files/new/src/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java) sequential? Discovering and merging runs can be done concurrently.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort#Operation):

> Timsort was designed to take advantage of runs of consecutive ordered elements that already exist in most real-world data, natural runs. It iterates over the data collecting elements into runs, and concurrently merging those runs together.

EDIT: The TimSort implementation in Java 9 is still sequential.

Comment: Suboptimal word choice. "Concurrently" as in the run collection and the merging are interleaved, rather than collecting all the runs before starting any merges.

Comment: Note that the source you're looking at is Java 7 - we're on Java 9 now.

Comment: @user2357112 My understanding was that run collection and merging could be interleaved. From Wikipedia: "Concurrently with the search for runs, the runs are merged with merge sort."

Comment: Because for 99.9% of the use cases, making it concurrent would make it significantly slower. Also because it must be able to sort objects which can be shared among several threads. Multi-threading is not a magic wand that makes everything faster. It has a cost.

Comment: There will be no parallel processing unless the application requests it. When you want the sorting in parallel, you can use `Arrays.parallelSort(…)` or `stream.parallel().sorted()…`. Besides that, @user2357112 already nailed it, concurrently does not mean multi-threaded here. Look at the beginning of the section: “It iterates over the data collecting elements into runs, and *simultaneously* merging those runs together”. That’s the meaning of “concurrently” here.

Comment: @Holger I see what you mean. Thanks for the explanation!